# Angular CLI's "ng serve" doesn't refer to typescript sources upon errors in chrome dev tools

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v8

I am trying to configure an app so that the chrome dev tools console refers to the typescript sources rather than the compiled javascript sources.

I have added the following line in an `ngOnInit` of our Dashboard component

```
throw new TypeError('Badaboomm!!');
```

Unfortunately chrome points me to the **js** file:

```
DashboardComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Badaboomm!!
    at DashboardComponent.ngOnInit (app-app-module.js:64409)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (provider.ts:212)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (view.ts:429)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (view.ts:389)
```

Here is our `angular.json` configuration:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "oneval": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "ovl",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/_styles.scss",
              "node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
              "node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-fresh.css",
              "node_modules/ag-grid/src/styles/ag-theme-material.scss",
              "node_modules/ag-grid/src/styles/ag-theme-balham.scss",
              "node_modules/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.css"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/styles",
                "src/styles/global",
                "src/styles/overrides",
                "src/styles/utils"
              ]
            },
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "int": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.int.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },
            "qua": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.qua.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },
            "sta": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.sta.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "oneval:build",
            "aot": false,
            "sourceMap": {
              "scripts": true,
              "styles": true,
              "vendor": true
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "oneval:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "oneval:build"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["src/tsconfig.app.json", "src/tsconfig.spec.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "oneval"
}
```

and out `tsconfig.json` configuration:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "types": ["jest"],
    "paths": {
      "@admin/*": ["src/app/admin/*"],
      "@core/*": ["src/app/core/*"],
      "@cache/*": ["src/app/cache/*"],
      "@dashboard/*": ["src/app/dashboard/*"],
      "@i18n/*": ["src/app/i18n/*"],
      "@material/*": ["src/app/material/*"],
      "@project-definition/*": ["src/app/project-definition/*"],
      "@prototype/*": ["src/app/prototype/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["src/app/shared/*"],
      "@validation/*": ["src/app/validation/*"],
      "@renault-shared/*": ["src/app/validation/renault/shared/*"],
      "@renault-applied/*": ["src/app/validation/renault/applied/*"],
      "@renault-standard/*": ["src/app/validation/renault/standard/*"],
      "@nissan/*": ["src/app/validation/nissan/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

I strongly suspect this issue started occurring after a `ng update`... Otherwise, I tried to create another angular app with `ng new someApp` and the issue does not occur. We use angular 8.

Can anyone please help?

**edit 1**: The issue (`js` sources instead of `ts` sources) appears especially upon force reload of the page...

**edit 2**: As mentioned in one of my comments in the chat, the issue seems to be related to the use of async/await and promises. The issue does not occur until async/await/promises are used.

**edit 3**: I have tried reproducing the issue by using async/await/promises on a new angular app, to no avail...

Comment: what about source tab ?

Comment: Typescript sources are available under the `localhost:4200` element of the `sources` tab.

Comment: So, you're running `ng serve` (with no additional params) and the issue doesn't take place. You do the force reload of the page, and the issue appears. Did I get you correct?

Comment: @SergeyMell Not quite. There also appears to be some randomness as to when the issue occurs.

Comment: Do you have a `disable cache` option turned on in your Dev Tools console?

Comment: @SergeyMell In the `network` tab you mean? There are no `disable cache` under the `console` tab...

Comment: Yes, sure. I meant `network` tab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197991/discussion-between-sergey-mell-and-balteo).

Comment: I get this if the page loads up with an error before I have opened up chrome dev tools. If I reload the page with dev tools open then the error has the typescript references included. Not sure if this helps in your situation...

Comment: @DoubleA. Thanks for your input. In my case the issue occurs even though the dev tools console has been opened before the error being thrown.

Comment: In development phase you can refer to the typescript source files!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `--source-map` to true in your configuration file. (dev & prod)

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    ...
    "sourceMap": false,
    ...
  }
}
```